# Solana/Web3.js: Does @Solana/web3.js support the current price for Solana?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, solana

I am currently using the @Solana/web3.js framework and want to grab the current price for Solana in order to convert a user's balance to USD .etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @solana/web3.js module currently concerns itself solely with interacting with native Solana programs as well as giving the tools to interact with the Solana blockchain via the RPC.

I recommend using [CoinGecko's API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) to find the current USD value of SOL and other tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a client side example, notice the url params

> ids=solana vs_currencies=usd

```js
var url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=solana&vs_currencies=usd";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [coin-ticker package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coin-ticker) to get SOL price from various exchanges.

Example:

```
const coinTicker = require('coin-ticker');
coinTicker('bitfinex', 'SOL_USD')
   .then((tick) => {
      console.log(tick.last)
   })
```